# C++ method name as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

How do I make the method name (here `some_method`) a template parameter?

```
template<typename T>
void sv_set_helper(T& d, bpn::array const& v) {
  to_sv(v, d.some_method());
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no such thing as a 'template identifier parameter', so you can't pass names as parameters. You could however take a member function pointer as argument:

```
template<typename T, void (T::*SomeMethod)()>
void sv_set_helper(T& d, bpn::array const& v) {
   to_sv(v, ( d.*SomeMethod )());
}
```

that's assuming the function has a `void` return type. And you will call it like this:

```
sv_set_helper< SomeT, &SomeT::some_method >( someT, v );
```

Comment: Thanks! Putting T::*SomeMethod in parentheses makes this solution work.

Answer (score 30):

Here is a simple example...

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename FType>
void bar(T& d, FType f) {
  (d.*f)(); // call member function
}


struct foible
{
  void say()
  {
    std::cout << "foible::say" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  foible f;
  bar(f,  &foible::say); // types will be deduced automagically...
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, you had the `.*f` part right before K-ballo, but his answer was first.