# How to get a C++ template class to invoke another class' methods?

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I have class A that needs to invoke the member functions of template class B.  Searching around I found this sample code on this site:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename FType>
void bar(T& d, FType f) {
  (d.*f)(); // call member function
}

struct foible
{
  void say()
  {
    std::cout << "foible::say" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  foible f;
  bar(f,  &foible::say); // types will be deduced automagically...
}
```

That came from this answer:
[C++ method name as template parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557990/c-method-name-as-template-parameter/7558035#7558035)

But it doesn't do 100% of what I need.  How would the above code be re-written so that:

1. method `bar` is a public member of a class and not a stand-alone
   function
2. arguments `d` and `f` which are getting passed to method `bar` are
   `public` members of the same class to which `bar` is a member,
   allowing `bar` to be of type `void (void)`
3. object type `foible` is a class and not a structure (optional)?

[EDIT 1] My own attempt at the rewrite which meets points 1) and 2) is the following, which is wrong:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, void (T::*FType)()>
class foo {
public:
  T obj;
  FType f;
void bar(void) {
  (obj.*f)(); // call member function
} // end bar
}; // end class foo

struct foible
{
  void say()
{
  std::cout << "foible::say" << std::endl;
}
};

int main(void)
{
foible f;
foo<foible, void (foible::*)()> c;
c.T = f;
c.Ftype = &foible::say;

c.bar(); // types will be deduced automagically...
}
```

My goal is to have an object of class type 'A' invoke the methods of object of class type 'B', so that when these methods execute the object of type 'B' can use its 'this' pointer to reference its local data.  I want to use function pointers inside class type 'A' so that these only need to be specified once, and I don't want one class to have to be derived from another.

Comment: What are you tring to do? What class do need to invoke the member of which other class?

Comment: "method bar is a public member of a class" Which class? If you mean the `T` class, then its not possible. Class definitions cannot be extended.

Comment: Your third point isn’t really meaningful: except for default visibility, struct = class in C++.

Comment: Replace `FType f;` with `void (T::*f)();` and you can remove the second template argument. After that you just need to use `c.obj/c.f` instead of `c.T/c.FType`.

Comment: Are you trying to implement `std::function` or a lambda function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A step by step solution:
 all examples uses the following class and foo function

```
#include <iostream>
class A
{
public:
    void foo(){std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;}
};
```

this sample works without template: just calling the calling A::foo with pointer to `A` and pointer to `A::foo`:

```
class B
{
public:
    A *a;
    void (A::*p)(); 

    void bar()
    {
        (a->*p)(); //call A::foo 
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    A a;
    B b;
    b.a = &a;
    b.p = &A::foo;
    b.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

The following sample added template `class T`, the pointer to foo method derived from `T`.

```
template <class T>
class C
{
public:
    T* t;
    void (T::*p)(); 
    C(T &o) : t(&o){} 
    void bar()
    {
        (t->*p)();
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    A a;
    C<A> c(a);
    c.p = &A::foo;
    c.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

in the following, the method pointer was templated too, but I don't see how can it be used since you should know how many argument to give it, but anyway:

```
template <class T, typename F>
class D
{
public:
    T* t;
    F p; 
    D(T &o, F pf) : t(&o),p(pf){} 
    void bar()
    {
        (t->*p)();
    }
};
int main(void)
{
    A a;
    D<A, void (A::*)()> d(a, &A::foo);
    d.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Example 'C' looks like it does everything I need.  How do I extend it so that the method pointer can take parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You are making that too complicated. Forget about pointers to methods. Currently there is no reason to use them.

Just do something like this:

```
template<typename F>
void bar(F f) {
  doSomething();

  f(someArg);

  doSomething();
}

int main(void)
{
  foible f;
  bar([&f](auto x) { f.someMagicMethod(x); } );

  return 0;
}
```

Note this approach is more flexible and readable than playing around with method pointers.